# Comparing the wrapper types in Java

Tags: java, long-integer

I have two `java.util.List` as follows.

```
List<Long> items = new ArrayList<Long>(){{
   add(141L);
   add(142L);           
}};

List<Long> itemsExist = new ArrayList<Long>(){{
    add(123L);
    add(124L);
    add(125L);
    add(126L);
    add(127L);
    add(141L);
    add(142L);            
}};
```

I was trying to remove the elements of the `List` named `items`, if they are contained in the `List` named `ItemsExist` as follows.

```
Iterator<Long> itemsIterator = items.iterator();

while(itemsIterator.hasNext())
{
    Long item1=itemsIterator.next();
    Iterator<Long> itemsExistIterator = itemsExist.iterator();

    while(itemsExistIterator.hasNext())
    {               
        Long item2=itemsExistIterator.next();
        if(item1==item2)
        {
            itemsIterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

But the removal of the elements (`141` and `142`) didn't happen because of this condition `if(item1==item2)` which actually should have been `if(item1.equals(item2))`, (I can understand the difference between `==` and `equals()`).

---

This could be emulated by a very simple example as follows.

```
Long a=new Long(5);
Long b=new Long(5);
System.out.println((a==b)+" : "+a.equals(b));
```

This returns `false` and `true` respectively.

---

The following example returns `true` in both comparisons.

```
Long a=5L;
Long b=5L;
System.out.println((a==b)+" : "+a.equals(b));
```

In this case, both `a` and `b` **also** appear to be the subject of unboxing which doesn't appear to be the case of the other examples. How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a part of the source code of java.lang.Long:

```
           private static class LongCache {
  544           private LongCache(){}
  545   
  546           static final Long cache[] = new Long[-(-128) + 127 + 1];
  547   
  548           static {
  549               for(int i = 0; i < cache.length; i++)
  550                   cache[i] = new Long(i - 128);
  551           }
  552       }

            public static Long valueOf(long l) {
  573           final int offset = 128;
  574           if (l >= -128 && l <= 127) { // will cache
  575               return LongCache.cache[(int)l + offset];
  576           }
  577           return new Long(l);
  578       }
```

It apears to me that the Long class maintains a cache of `Long` objects between -128 and 127. So a and b variables in your example points to the same object `Long`.

Comment: Sadly counter-intuitive, and Integer does the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just like `String pool` java maintains a pool for integer values in the range -128 to +127. A similar question was already answered in this site. Please refer [Why does the behavior of the Integer constant pool change at 127?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098143/java-integer-constant-pool)

Just to summarize, if you are assigning an integer in the range of -128 to +127 as a literal, it will be picked up from the integer pool and the same object will be returned every time you use the same literal.

eg,

```
Integer int1 = 123;
Integer int2 = 123; // Get the same object from integer pool
System.out.println(int1.equals(int2));
System.out.println(int1== int2);
```

The above code gets you true in both conditions.

If you are creating an object using `new` operator, a new object will be created everytime and the Integer pool will not come into picture. 
eg,

```
Integer int1 = new Integer(123);
Integer int2 = new Integer(123); // Gets you a new object
System.out.println(int1.equals(int2));
System.out.println(int1== int2);
```

`equals` methods get you true and `==` check gets you false. 
You can get more insights here http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42276