# Where are int values and Integer Objects created?

Tags: java

When we initialize some integer values like

```
int a = 10;
```

or

```
Integer b = new Integer(20);
Integer b = 30;
```

where are those objects created in memory?

Is there any concept like Integer-Pool like we have String-Pool for String?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494461/java-integer-pool-why

Answer (score 4):

Most JVMs (even 64-bit ones) use 32-bit references. (Newer JVMs uses 32-bit references for heaps up to almost 32 GB) The reference is on the stack or in a CPU register and is not usually counted. The Integer is allocated on the heap.

```
Integer i = new Integer(1); // creates a new object every time.
Integer j = 1; // use a cached value.
```

`Integer a;` will allocate memory in stack to hold the reference value and initialized with null

`new` creates instance in `heap` memory

Comment: we know that the code Integer a = 127; is an example of auto-boxing and compiler automatically converts this line to Integer a = Integer.valueOf(127);.

So, it is the Integer.valueOf() method that is returning these integer objects, which means this method must be doing something under the hood.                        _i am confused, Integer a; in heap or stack?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/java-integer-cache-why-integervalueof127-integerva

Answer (score 3):

Objects created with `new` keyword are stored on *heap*.

Variables (references to those objects) and primitive types like `int` are stored on program's *stack*.

`Integer` is not a special class in Java. You can use arithmetic operators with it, it's immutable and you can even use `==` for equality testing (in the range of -128 to 127 since those values are already cached).

> Is there any concept like Integer-Pool like we have String-Pool for String?

Open the code of `java.lang.Integer` and look at the `valueOf` method. It's obvious that they indeed use an Integer pool.

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

---

Also, I think this image will be helpful for you:

[image]

Comment: "Objects [...] are stored on the heap." Maybe you should read some words about [_escape analysis_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis). Actually, this qualifies your statement to be w̶r̶o̶n̶g̶  not entirely true.

Comment: Yeah, let's go into that to explain it to someone who is learning OO at the moment. We should definitely start with escape analysis and JVM enhancements (before he understands the difference between the stack and the heap).

Comment: Yes, I know that you should not overwhelm beginners with too much technical details. Nevertheless, this statement is not correct _as it is_. Other readers might be more advanced. A good explanation should be short and correct. Let the readers decide whether to dig into details or not (hyperlinks, heh?).

Comment: When I see place for improvement in somebody's comment I edit it. For the same reason, i.e. to make them more exact, correct and easy to understand. If you see place for improving my comment, please do so. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score -1):

`Integer`s in the range -128 to +127 are pre-created. You can think of those as being in an "integer pool".

Any other value is created at runtime.

This leads to some subtle behaviour in Java:

The expression `boo == far` for two `Integer` values `foo` and `bar` will be `true` if their values are equal *and* in the range -128 to +127. It will not be true for values outside that range: you need to use `.equals` for such values.

Personally I find that pernicious: **Never** use `==` on boxed types.

Comment: Is this also the case for new Integer(20)? I thought this is only true for boxing.

Comment: Nope. It isn't true for new Integer(20), as that will always create a new object. It's only true for Autoboxing, as this uses the `valueOf` method, where the pre-created values are used.