# 500 != 500 java Integer please explain

Tags: java

```
public class Demo{
 public static void main(String[] arr){
      Integer num1 = 100;
      Integer num2 = 100;
     Integer num3 = 500;
     Integer num4 = 500;
     System.out.println(num3==num4);
     if(num1==num2){
         System.out.println("num1 == num2");
      }
     else{
         System.out.println("num1 != num2");
     }
     if(num3 == num4){
         System.out.println("num3 == num4");
     }
     else{
         System.out.println("num3 != num4");
     }
  }
}
```

the o/p:

```
false
num1 == num2
num3 != num4`
```

why is the 2nd if statement i.e(num3 == num4) false where both number has the same value 500 please explain

Comment: Don't compare `Integer` objects using `==`. Only compare *objects* using `equals()`. If you wanted `==` comparison, you should have used the `int` primitive type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer is an Object and need to use `equals` to compare. Direct `==` is comparing the reference whether pointing the same object, which is not what you want to achieve. Regarding the num1 == num2, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494461/java-integer-pool-why) link for details. Small numbers are interim to save memory in Java. So when comparing `num1` and `num2` they are actually referring the same object. While `num3` and `num4` they refer stand-alone objects respectively.