# Integer comparison with ==

Tags: java, integer

I was writing some test code and found one strange thing, and still confused how this is happening?

```
Integer i1 = 220;
Integer i2 = 220;

System.out.println(i1 == i2);
```

prints **false** as expected. But

```
Integer i1 = 20;
Integer i2 = 20;

System.out.println(i1 == i2);
```

prints **true**, but both are different references referring to different objects (I assume that).

How come second snippet prints **true**?

Comment: Or refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098143/java-integer-constant-pool

Comment: The general lesson though is: don't do this.

Comment: I understand equals is for comparison, but why to have confusion in mind?

Comment: Or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` operator only works for `Integer` values between -128 and 127. That is why it doesn't work for 220 but does for 20. In general it is best to always use `.equals()` when comparing `Integers` and you should never rely on the `==` operator.

More information can be found here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching