# Thread Synchronization on Integer instance variable

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Creating objects for class Check(2 different objects)
        Check c = new Check("s1");
        Check c1 = new Check("s2");
        c.start();c1.start();
   }
}
class Check extends Thread{
    Check(String name){super(name);}
    private Integer ab = 2;
    public void run(){
        synchronized (ab) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Here i have synchronized on the variable ab. And i have created two different instances of class Check also, but i am always getting output for s1 followed by s2 or vice versa, but not mixed, why is that so? when i have already created two separate objects(in main), so two different threads, two different ab variables, so how it becomes a shared resource for the two different objects?

Comment: B.T.W., you are not synchronizing on the _variable_, you are synchronizing on the object to which the variable refers.  It's an important distinction because some people have made the mistake of not realiznig that variable can refer to different objects at different times, and some have made the mistake of not realizing that the same object can be referenced by more than one variable.

Comment: This code looks more like a test-code than a real case, but if you want to synchronize on a lock-free, but thread-safe, [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), you can use an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: @jameslarge: I understand, what you are saying. I was not precise onto that because my problem focused on some other point. Anyways, thanks. :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: Yes, its a test-code, no relevance to real projects. Just checking out. Yes, AtomicInteger, i know that. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Jean-François: to clarify, atomicinteger is more an alternative to locking, it's not something you should use as a lock.

Comment: @NathanHughes True.

Comment: While in this specific case, both threads are synchronizing on the same `Integer` instance, it should be emphasized, that there is nothing wrong with two threads apparently running one after another. If two threads do not synchronize, they have no timing relationship at all, not even a parallel running guaranty. So one appearing to run entirely after another, is an entirely plausible outcome *especially* for short running threads like the two of the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL;DR - it's because of `Integer` pooling. Make ab an `Object` (i.e. `Object ab = new Object()`) to guarantee that each instance of `Check`'s locking doesn't interfere with the others.

---

I was initially puzzled as well. Interestingly enough, if you change

```
private Integer ab = 2;
```

to

```
private Object ab = new Object();
```

the synchronization goes away (you get different outputs on every run). Back with ab as an `Integer`, I ran your code in debug mode (with a breakpoint on the print thread name line) and found the following. Here's the first thread:

[image: First thread variables]

And here's the second thread.

[image: Second thread variables]

Notice that it's actually the same object, `Integer@443`. Even though you thought you were getting two different objects, both `ab` fields in the two Check instances refer to the same object in memory! Therefore yes, there is correct synchronization. The question, then, is how saying `Integer ab = 2` twice gets you the same `Integer` object in memory.

---

By saying `Integer ab = 2`, you are using *autoboxing*, by which a primitive value (of type `int`) is automatically converted into the corresponding Object type `Integer`. This is equivalent to calling the autoboxing method call:

```
private Integer ab = Integer.valueOf(2);
```

If we look into `Integer.valueOf`, we notice that it has a pool for values within a certain range:

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

For most conventional settings, this will include the value `2`. Thus you are getting the same `Integer` value in memory when you call this method.

Comment: Really interesting one. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: The *"certain range"* is from -128 to 127 by default. Note that IntegerCache.high can be altered. IntegerCache.low can't.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because of **Ingeter Pool** concept in java.

Integers ranging between -128 and 127 (inclusive), are used in same way as String pool.

So, when you use `private Integer ab = 2;`, ab is shared for both objects of `Check`.

You can use value > 128 or any other type of object so that your code won't be synchronized.

You may look at answers here: [Why does the behavior of the Integer constant pool change at 127?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098143/why-does-the-behavior-of-the-integer-constant-pool-change-at-127) for understanding Integer Pool concept.

Comment: If you need explicitly distinct objects you should explicitly create them. Using larger integers will give you distinct objects in current implementations but is not gauranteed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at bytecode you would probably see this code:

```
LINENUMBER 15 L1
ALOAD 0
ICONST_2
INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Integer.valueOf (I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
PUTFIELD com/example/Check.ab : Ljava/lang/Integer;
```

Java tries to box the primitive value `2` to object by calling `#valueOf` of `Integer` class. And as we know, `Integer`'s `valueOf` implements [Flyweight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) pattern. Thus, the same object is shared between instances.