# Stack.peek() comparison returns wrong result for -1024

Tags: java, java-8, stack

I take two stacks `s1` and `s2`, initialize them with some values, and eventually, both have `-1024` as there `top`.

Now, if I compare peeks of both in an `if` condition, the results are coming wrong. For example:

```
if (s1.peek() == s2.peek()) --> returns false
```

Even when both peeks have `-1024` as the values.

**BUT**

If I take the values in different variables, and then compare, that works just fine. For example:

```
int first = s1.peek();
int second = s2.peek();
if (first == second) --> returns true
```

I checked same with other values (eg 10). Direct peek comparison works fine in that case.

Am I doing something wrong by comparing peeks directly or is this related to values being compared somehow?

Below is the minimal coded example (I was doing this just as a practice to implement min stack problem):

```
public class MinStack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MinStack minStack = new MinStack();
        minStack.push(512);
        minStack.push(-1024);
        minStack.push(-1024);
        minStack.push(512);
        minStack.pop();
        System.out.print(minStack.getMin());
        minStack.pop();
        System.out.print(minStack.getMin());
        minStack.pop();
        System.out.print(minStack.getMin());
    }

    Stack<Integer> originalStack;
    Stack<Integer> minStack;

    /** initialize your data structure here. */
    public MinStack() {
        originalStack = new Stack<>();
        minStack = new Stack<>();
    }

    public void push(int x) {
        originalStack.push(x);
        if(minStack.isEmpty() || minStack.peek() >= x)
            minStack.push(x);
    }

    public void pop() {
        if(originalStack.peek() == minStack.peek())
            minStack.pop();
        originalStack.pop();
    }

    public int top() {
        return originalStack.peek();
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return minStack.peek();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the type that you're pushing onto the stack?

Comment: have you tried `s1.peek().equals(s2.peek())`?

Comment: @dehasi no, but as my stack is having integer values, never thought about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of `Integer` interning. `java.lang.Integer` objects representing small values, such as `10`, are pre-manufactured, so when you push autoboxed `10` on two separate stacks, the same object is pushed.

Once you get to the place in your code where you `peek()`, the same object is returned for `10`, yet two different objects are returned for `-1024`. That is why `==` returns true for `10`, but not for `-1024`.

When you add `int` variables to receive the `peek()`-ed values, auto-unboxing takes care of harvesting `int`s of the same value from `Integer`, so the code with `-1024` works again.

You can fix this by replacing `==` with `equals` in your conditional:

```
if (s1.peek().equals(s2.peek())) --> returns true
```

Comment: Perhaps you should check, if the `s1` stack is not empty before checking for equality with `!s1.isEmpty()`

Comment: @gil.fernandes I agree, generally you would. However, it looks like OPs code relies on `Stack`'s code throwing an exception in this situation.

Comment: Can you please explain the `pre-manufactured` part more and maybe why it is done for some values and not for some others.

Comment: @DroidDev This is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)). More info could be found [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13098143/335858).

Comment: I meet the exact same problem! And I'm very confused, thanks for the explain though I don't understand what is `pre-manufactured` or `autoboxed`. At least I know what I should check.