# Which inbuilt java classes other than String uses pooling?

Tags: java, pool

Which inbuilt java classes other than String uses pooling?
For example we have String which uses pooling,what are the other inbuit java classes that uses pooling?

Comment: `Threads` come to mind...

Answer (score 2):

The `Integer` has a pool with a pool with all the values between `-128` and `127`.

If you do:

```
Integer x = 127;
Integer y = 127;
System.out.println(x == y);
```

you'd get `true` as an output, but if you change that to:

```
Integer x = 128;
Integer y = 128;
System.out.println(x == y);
```

then you'd get `false`, as `128` is not part of the pool and `x` and `y` actually represent two different objects.

More info:

- [Why does the behavior of the Integer constant pool change at 127?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098143/why-does-the-behavior-of-the-integer-constant-pool-change-at-127)

Comment: [Between *at least* -128 and 127](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-), and you can configure the JVM to cache values outside this range too.

Answer (score 0):

am not sure if it fits the bill, [`java.net.InetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) uses dns resolution (domain to ip translation) cache. it actually has two caches - for positive as well as negative lookups.

Comment: I view caching and polling as two different things.