# Long and Double comparison (==) behaves differently

Tags: java

When executing the following code snippet it behaves differently for Double.

```java
Long v1 = 1L;
Long v2 = 1L;
Double d1 = 1.0;
Double d2 = 1.0;

System.out.println(v1 == v2); // Prints true
System.out.println(d1 == d2); // Prints false

System.out.println(v1.equals(v2)); // Prints true
System.out.println(d1.equals(d2)); // Prints true
```

Why Double `==` behaves differently from Long?

Comment: @Tschallacka I doubt it does.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098143/why-does-the-behavior-of-the-integer-constant-pool-change-at-127  Probably something similar going on for Longs. That is, for small values there's a pool of existing `Long` instances that will be used instead of creating new instances all the time.

Comment: because `==` checks for object identity, not equality

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name heh, didn't notice he invoked Objects. Yea, that'd do it.

Comment: Unrelated to this problem, but comparing floating point values in general is not as easy as one might expect. See e.g. [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Long v1 = 1L;
Long v2 = 1L;
Double d1 = 1.0;
Double d2 = 1.0;
```

You are creating two references to objects here, and instantiating two objects with autoboxing behaviour of Java.

Java re-uses the same Long object instance from a pool for v1 and v2, The Doubles do not use a pool for remembering values, as can be read in this informative blog entry https://gerardnico.com/code/type/autoboxing

> Here are some rules as with Java 5 :
>
> autoboxing to Boolean and Byte always returns an object from the pool
>   autoboxing to Char, Short, Integer and Long returns an object from the
>   pool when the autoboxed value is between -128 and 127 (inclusive)
>   **autoboxing of Float and Double does not use the pool and always
>   returns a new object**

Your code becomes then with autoboxing(some pool is a visualisation of the pool java uses to cache certain values):

```
class SomePoolJavaUses {
   static Long _l1 = new Long(1L);
   static Long _l2 = new Long(2L);
   static Long _l3 = new Long(3L);
   ...
}

Long v1 = SomePoolJavaUses._l1;
Long v2 = SomePoolJavaUses._l1;
Double d1 = new Double(1.0);
Double d2 = new Double(1.0);
```

This means that d1 and d2 are not equal instances, so they are not equal in ==
This means that v1 and v2 are equal instance, so they are equal in ==

the `v1.equals` returns true, because there is being looked at the actual value there instead of a quick check if the memory addresses are the same.