# Comparison of int to Integer not working after adding to Linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list, int, integer

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int var = 128;
     Integer i = var;
     int j = var;
     LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<>();
     ll.add(var);
     System.out.println(i==j);
     System.out.println(i==ll.peek()); 
 }
```

```
Output:
true
false
```

The values of variable var below number 128 though gives correct output as:

```
Output:
true
true
```

Please explain why comparison fails for peek() on values above 127?

Comment: You're not comparing an int to an Integer. You're comparing an Integer to another Integer. So you should use `equals` rather than `==`

Comment: I think you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098143/why-does-the-behavior-of-the-integer-constant-pool-change-at-127) question and you will get partial answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
System.out.println(i.equals(ll.peek()));
```

Remember, `==` compares the references, not the content.

Check [Why is 128==128 false but 127==127 is true when comparing Integer wrappers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-is-128-128-false-but-127-127-is-true-when-comparing-integer-wrappers-in-ja) to understand why it returned `true` for a number less than `128`.

Comment: how come == works at all if it is comparing the references?

Comment: @JunisvaultCo - do you mean how `i==j` returns `true`? If yes, that is because of [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: he stated that i==ll.peek() returns true for var<128. And indeed, I've tested it with 127 andi t does. Why? It is comparing references.

Comment: @JunisvaultCo have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098143/why-does-the-behavior-of-the-integer-constant-pool-change-at-127)

Comment: @michalk thanks! that's crazy

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the Integer constant pool. Java maintains Integer pool from -128 to 127

```
private static class IntegerCache {
        static final int low = -128;
        static final int high;  //set to 127
}
```

So for values between -128 to 127, same reference would be returned from cache but for other values new Integer object would be created.

Answer (score 0):

the operator `==` checks for reference equality.
Because `Integer i` is a Class type, as well as the returned value of `ll.peak()`, you should use the `equals()` method to compare them.