# Why Kotlin '===' reference equality operator returns false for same object references?

Tags: kotlin, nullable, equality, boxing, autoboxing

The example are from Kotlin official website

```
    val a: Int = 100
    val boxedA: Int? = a
    val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a     

    val b: Int = 100
    val boxedB: Int? = b
    val anotherBoxedB: Int? = b

    println(a === a)  // true
    println(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // true
    println(boxedB === anotherBoxedB) // true
```

I understood above example.
But when I change the value of *a* and *b* from *100* to *1000*, the output changes to *false* from *true* like below :

```
    val a: Int = 1000
    val boxedA: Int? = a
    val anotherBoxedA: Int? = a     
    
    val b: Int = 1000
    val boxedB: Int? = b
    val anotherBoxedB: Int? = b

    println(a === a)  // true
    println(boxedA === anotherBoxedA) // false
    println(boxedB === anotherBoxedB) // false
```

Can anyone help by changing value from **100** to **1000**, why output of **===** operator is changing?

What is happening with respect to autoboxing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098143/why-does-the-behavior-of-the-integer-constant-pool-change-at-127

Comment: Thanks @DiegoMarin, this link helped me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auto-boxing uses a cache for the small integers (I guess up to 127), Therefore you get the same object if you box a small integer, but a different one if you box a large integer.