# Unboxing int value using Integer Class

Tags: java, logical-operators, unboxing

In this circumstance what is the value of variable `y` after the first two statements? I'm assuming it's Integer 7 but my book says `automatic unboxing` of objects only occurs with relational operators < >". I'm a little confused how  variable `Integer y` gets it's value. Does any `unboxing` occur in `newInteger(x)`?

```
Integer x = 7;
Integer y = new Integer(x); 

println( "x == y" + " is " +  (x == y))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly does comparing Integers with == do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689745/what-exactly-does-comparing-integers-with-do)

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan i understand what happens when == compares two objects but I don't understand how `y` gets its value.

Comment: Note that `"x == y" + " is " +  x == y` means: `("x == y" + " is " +  x) == y`, which is not what you want. Use parentheses: `"x == y" + " is " +  (x == y)`

Comment: @Jesper i didn't even notice that mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Integer x = 7;
```

In this case, the `int` literal 7 is automatically boxed into the `Integer` variable `x`.

```
Integer y = new Integer(x);
```

This involves an automatic unboxing of the `Integer` variable `x` into an `int` (temporary) variable, which is passed to the `Integer` constructor. In other words, it is equivalent to:

```
Integer y = new Integer(x.intValue());
```

After this statement, `y` points to a new object that is different than `x` but containing the same `int` wrapped value.

Comment: So x in `new Integer(x)` is temporarily unboxed to value type `int` so the integer constructor for variable y could take effect. The sequence of boxing and unboxing was a little confusing to me at first. Now it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Ian Yes it does unboxing because the constructor takes a primitive `int`, not the `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

Unboxing happens when the compiler is **certain** that you wish to compare **values**. Using `==` can compare the `Objects` and therefore give `false` because `==` is a valid operation between objects. With `<` and `>` there is no concept of `Object < OtherObject` so it is certain that you mean numerically.

```
public void test() {
    Integer x = 7;
    Integer y = new Integer(x) + 1;

    System.out.println("x == y" + " is " + (x == y));
    System.out.println("x.intValue() == y.intValue()" + " is " + (x.intValue() == y.intValue()));
    System.out.println("x < y" + " is " + (x < y));
    System.out.println("x.intValue() < y.intValue()" + " is " + (x.intValue() < y.intValue()));
}
```

> x == y is false
>
> x.intValue() == y.intValue() is true
>
> x < y is true
>
> x.intValue() < y.intValue() is true

---

> In this circumstance what is the value of variable y after the first two statements?

The value of the variable `y` is a **reference to an Integer object containing the value 7**.